# Adding JS Validation on CompareValidator

Tags: c#, javascript, validation, comparevalidator

is it possible to add a JS validation function for CompareValidator?
i can't use a CustomValidator.

Comment: You want to compare what values?

Comment: i want to compare dates, but since the application can handle different date formats, the comparevalidator is not working properly. so i guess if i can create my own validation function it would be much better. i am currenly overriding BaseValidator to solve my issue, but with this solution i should go back to every page and rename the validators..

Comment: Why can't you use a CustomValidator? That might help us help you better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure whether you still need it or not, I assume not however since this is unanswered...

Well, you can't do it directly, however you can hide original function which is responsible for CompareValidator validation and introduce new one. This is possible because all validation functions comes from ASP.NET in global scope which is... controversial, but helpful in that case.

Please find following module which get the job done. It exposes you two methods. First called **addFunction** allows you to add one or more functions for custom validation. This function should returns **Boolean** and it consumes three parameters **Validator object** , **TargetObject** and **CompareObject** respectively. Second one called **disableOldFunction** allows you to completely get rid of old validation function which is called by the module if all your functions are valid.

```
    var MyModules = {};
    MyModules.CompareValExtension = function ()
    {
        var functions = new Array();
        var oldFunc = null, disabled = false;

        function myCompareValidatorEvaluateIsValid(val)
        {
            var valid = true;
            if (oldFunc && functions.length)
            {
                for (i in functions)
                {
                    valid = functions[i](val, document.getElementById(val.controltovalidate), document.getElementById(val.controltocompare));
                    if (!valid) { break; }
                }
                if (!disabled && valid)
                {
                    valid = oldFunc(val);
                }
            }
            return valid;
        }

        if (typeof CompareValidatorEvaluateIsValid != 'undefined')
        {
            oldFunc = CompareValidatorEvaluateIsValid;
            window.CompareValidatorEvaluateIsValid = myCompareValidatorEvaluateIsValid;
        }

        var me = {};
        me.addFunction = function (func) { if (typeof func == "function") { functions.push(func); } }
        me.disableOldFunction = function () { disabled = true; }
        return me;
    } ();
```

Example usage:

```
    MyModules.CompareValExtension.addFunction(function (val, elem, comp)
    {
        return elem.value == "my value"; 
    });
    MyModules.CompareValExtension.disableOldFunction();
```

*Caveat:* Please place this module somewhere on the page bottom to be sure that default validation scripts are in place already. You can also rewrite module a bit to defer initialization until document will be ready.